# What's the purpose of doing: x.map { _ => () }

Tags: scala, slick, play-slick

I have been looking at some of the Play Slick examples for building the data access layer and found the following line in the [CatDAO example](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/basic/app/dao/CatDAO.scala#L19) a bit intriguing:

```
def insert(cat: Cat): Future[Unit] = db.run(Cats += cat).map { _ => () }
```

and I wonder what's the purpose of doing `.map { _ => () }`

**UPDATE**: running the following in the Scala interpreter provides some clue but still it is not entirely clear why it is needed in the insert method above.

```
scala> val test = Seq(1, 2, 3)
test: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> test map { _ => () }
res0: Seq[Unit] = List((), (), ())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without that mapping `db.run` method would return a number of records that were inserted into the database (returning type would be `Future[Int]` then). Yet the author of the code doesn't need that value, and he would like his API to return `Future[Unit]` instead. That's why he's using that `map`, which maps `Int` to `Unit` in this case (`()` is a value representing `Unit` type).

Comment: Probably it would be then more clear doing `.map { _ => Unit }` a bit more typing for the sake of clarity, or?

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work the same, because `Unit` is a type, and `()` is an instance of that type. So your map would return a sequence of types (`Seq[Unit.type]`) and not a sequence of instances of that type (`Seq[Unit]`)